# Windows IDE for Haskell

Tags: windows, haskell, visual-studio-code, ide, atom-editor

I need to setup a simple and compelling dev environment for small proyects written in Haskell in Windows machines for freshmen.

I have tried several ways to integrate Haskell into VSCode in Windows with no success.

I had a nice setup a few years ago, but I´m finding problems with dependencies recreating that environment:

- Editor: Atom
- Global binaries build using: stack with ghc-mod hlint stylish-haskell
- Atom plugins: language-haskell, ide-haskell, ide-haskell-repl, haskell-ghc-mod

It seems that the "cool" way right now is Language Server Protocol + VScode. ghc-mod seems not to be mantained anymore, Intero has reached EOL, HEI is merging with another project... Having a stable and updated dev environment looks like a moving target.

So, the question is: **does anyone have reproducible step-by-step instructions for having VSCode working with Haskell in Windows?**

I will test any suggestion in a fresh Windows 10 64bits VM and report the results.

Note: VSCode + Docker container is not an option. Most of the student´s machines have 4GB RAM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool called [ghcid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcid) (not to be confused with [ghcide](https://github.com/digital-asset/ghcide)) that, while nowhere near a full-blown IDE, is pretty robust and provides some niceties like re-compiling on save and showing compile errors. It doesn't support go-to-definition though. It has a VSCode plugin.

Here's a possible way of setting up things in Windows:

- Download the GHC 8.8.3 binaries for Windows from [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_8_3.html#windows64).
- Download the cabal-install 3.0.0.0 binaries for Windows from [here](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html).
- Decompress them in some folder.
- Add entries to your PATH environment variable so that it has access to the `/bin` folder of the GHC installation and to the folder containing the `cabal` executable.
- Open a Powershell console.
- Run `cabal udpate`
- Run `cabal install --install-method=copy --installdir=somefolder ghcid` to install the `ghcid` executable, where "somefolder" is the destination folder. (If the installation fails, try running the command from a Git Bash or Cygwin terminal as a workaround.) Put the destination folder in PATH.
- Open (or restart) VSCode and install the "Haskell Syntax Highlighting" and [haskell-ghcid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ndmitchell.haskell-ghcid) plugins.
- Go to an example cabal project, use the `Ctrl-Shift-P` shortcut, and execute the `Start ghcid` action. The ghcid terminal will appear.

Example of a ghcid session showing an error:

[image]

The haskell-ghcid plugin can read a .ghcid file in the project root containing flags that should be passed to the ghcid command.

---

Extra instructions to set up code formatting:

- Install the [ormulu](https://github.com/tweag/ormolu) formatter by running `cabal install  ormolu  --install-method=copy --installdir=somefolder`. Again, make sure that the destination folder in in PATH.
- Open (or restart) VSCode and install the [ormulu](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sjurmillidahl.ormolu-vscode) plugin.

Now the "Format Document" and "Format Selection" actions in VSCode will use ormulu.

---

Another way of installing GHC and getting to ghcid and ormulu could be by using the [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) tool, which handles GHC installation by itself.

Comment: I would also point out that you don’t _need_ to use `ghcid` with VSCode. `ghcid` is perfectly usable as a standalone tool — in fact, it was designed to be used by itself, and only integrated into other development environments later.